# Breeze: Using Predicate with a Decimal DataType

Tags: odata, breeze

I am trying to create a `Predicate` using a decimal data type but I get the following error:

```
Error retrieving data.A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. 
Found operand types 'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Double' for operator kind 'Equal'. 
Error: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types   
'Edm.Decimal' and 'Edm.Double' for operator kind 'Equal'.
```

Here is the code I am trying it with:

```
// engineSize equals 1.4 in this case.
predicate.create('engineLitreCapacity', '==', engineSize);
```

Comment: Good answer for same problem here [in this link][1]. Thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609998/breeze-predicate-for-decimal-type/27611461#27611461

Answer (score 2):

I'had the same issue. I found the mistery :)... I think that's somethings in naming convention related to metadata and the REST service controller sign: Eg:

Doesn't work

```
    /*Breeze Controller Server Side*/
        [HttpGet]
            public IQueryable<Product> Items()
            {
                return _contextProvider.Context.Products;
            }

   /*Client*/ 
    query = breeze.EntityQuery
                         .from("Items")
                         .where(Predicate.create('BasePrice', >', 1)
                         .orderBy(sortString)
                         .select(selectData)
                         .skip(skip)
                         .take(take)
                         .inlineCount();
```

It' works !!

```
/*Breeze Controller Server Side*/
 [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Product> Products()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Products;
    }

 /*Client*/ 
 query = breeze.EntityQuery
                 .from("Products")
                 .where(Predicate.create('BasePrice', >', 1)
                 .orderBy(sortString)
                 .select(selectData)
                 .skip(skip)
                 .take(take)
                 .inlineCount();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `parseFloat` the `engineSize`:

```
predicate.create('engineLitreCapacity', '==', parseFloat(engineSize));
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the datatype in metadata for the 'engineLitreCapacity' and does it match the datatype on your database for the same field?  If not, how was your metadata initialized, via a FetchMetadata call or was it created by hand?