# breeze.Predicate for Decimal Type

Tags: javascript, breeze, predicate

is there a way to create a breeze predicate for a property that its type is Edm.Decimal?

because the datatype in next expression is always double and I don't find a way to say to  breeze that I just need create a predicate for a decimal type and not double type, because in final url request I got '10.53**d**' value instead '10.53**m**' value, then the server answer me with an error.

var p = new breeze.Predicate( 'UnitPrice' , '>=', 10.53);

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always explicitly state the dataType in any query like this:

```
var p = new breeze.Predicate('UnitPrice', ">=", 
       { value: 10.53, dataType: breeze.DataType.Decimal });
```

However, this shouldn't be necessary if you have the metadata for the EntityType available on the client. In that case, the EntityQuery will, by default, assume that the dataType is what is specified in the metadata for each property.

The only reason that it should assume Double vs Decimal is if no EntityType metadata is available for the specified property.

Comment: A lot of thanks Jay Traband, I spent a lot of time finding this excellent answer, but see, I tried second part first, I mean, I created the predicate once metadata is in client, but I got same issue, there's no way, even with metadata in hands, to know the 'UnitPrice' property dataType because when I'm creating the predicate I'm not specifying which entityType has this property, 'Order entityType' in this case. So Jay, what I'm missing here? or am I wrong in something? Thanks.

Comment: The predicate is only meaningful once it is applied to an EntityQuery, which always has an EntityType and the final url resolution does not occur until then. So the same predicate may get resolved to different urls depending on the EntityType. How are you using the predicate without an EntityType.

Comment: This is my way.  var query = new breeze.EntityQuery(); var p = new breeze.Predicate(...); query = query.where(p); query= query.from(name); entityManager.executeQuery(query).then(function(data){ defer.resolve(data); });.

Comment: I don't know other way to associate an EntityType with an EntityQuery. For now I just add the .from(EntityTypeName) clause when I'm building the query. This is the way to bind an EntityQuery with an EntiyType for me right now.

Comment: Using the from clause is correct, but I think I see your problem.  The '.from' clause takes a 'resource' name and not an 'EntityTypeName'.  Take a look at this: http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/querying-locally ( section is titled "ResourceNames are not EntityType names").

Comment: ok Jay, I read the section but in my case the resource name is equal to my EntityType name, 'Order' for both cases. Anyways I saw how associate an entityQuery with an EntityType. 'toType('')' clause. So Jay a lot of thanks for your time and don't you think that my question deserves an up vote (I need it)? Thanks Jay.

Comment: It may be that your "Order" resource name in your query is NOT in fact registered as the `defaultResourceName` for the type. You can add more resourceName-type mappings. There's a new documentation page, ["query from"](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/query-from) dedicated to the topic of resource names and their relationship to EntityTypes.